# Its vs it's when "it" is the noun?

Tags: pronouns, it-its-itself

When used as pronoun, it's "its", but what if "it" is used as the word "it" itself, a noun?

For example:

"Its function is to substitute a neuter object."

vs.

"It's function is to substitute a neuter object."

The first one sounds like it's about an object from context, not the word "it", and the second one I have mixed feelings about.

Comment: We'd be most likely to say *the function of 'it' is.....*

Comment: If your use of "it" here is to refer to the word "it" (or "its" or "it's", then it should be in quotes, and you should avoid the plural and possessive.  After all, you wouldn't say "'Mary Had a Little Lamb''s an old nursery rhyme."  It's would be "'Mary Had a Little Lamb' is an old nursery rhyme."